# Import looks fine in texture preview but not material preview--why?

Tags: texturing, materials, blender-internal-render-engine, import

I'm new to Blender. I've imported an OBJ scene and am using Blender Internal to render. The preview looks fine in "texture" mode. But a single object (the door) becomes the default color in "material" mode and when rendered. I've compared the settings between the objects and they look the same to me but obviously are not. What should I be looking for and why would this happen with an OBJ & MTL file?

Thank you,
d. vyd[image: Blender texture preview][image: Blender materials preview]

Comment: Basically you can't purely rely on imported materials, you have to make your own using the textures.

Comment: This has answered my main question regarding the missing material on the door--I will mark the question as answered. However, perhaps someone can explain why the wall and step materials seem to have been imported fine?

Comment: The importer does try to read and recreate the materials using the provided textures, it is however very unreliable and will often fail, especially for complex ones. Also viewport materials are meant as visual reference and are not representative of the final rendered appearance.